# Spring Tool Suite - ApplicationContext not found

Tags: spring

I am just setting out trying to learn about Spring. I installed Spring Tool Suite as springsource.org says that is the way to go. I created a "Spring Project" and typed in the first example in the book I'm looking at - but when I try to import ApplicationContext, it isn't found. Is that right? Do I need to find the jar that is in and add it to the project's Build Path before I can import it? I would have thought that a Spring Tool Suite would, at the very least, take care of that?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: showing us your codes might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is that right? Do I need to find the jar that is in and add it to the project's Build Path before I can import it?

I don't know whether STS will add those libraries or not. But you can download those libraries from springsource [download page](http://www.springsource.org/download/community). Add them in your project's classpath. I had created an application using STS but it didn't add libraries and I had added those.

Answer (score 0):

Spring tool suite is just a IDE with many eclipse plugins. Please download spring library first here: http://www.springsource.org/download/community, and then add all the corredsponding jar files to your build path(here you need org.springframework.context.jar).